# how can i split values of x axis in scroller in vegalite

Tags: visualization, vega-lite, vega, vega-embed, vega-lite-api

I want to create chart  in Vega lite but facing issue while x axis label is overlapping. I want x axis label not overlap it must break if it going out of rect box size and just display below it and map that values in scroller too i.e.(concat1).  [editor link](https://vega.github.io/editor/?#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJghgLhIFygG4QDYFcCmBneBtUA0hgJ4D6kM8IsANONgMYBOAlgA5QsD2AdlQIIBRAEoB5AAoAZfgDlBIAL41CJctFhwQAIxB0wjVh259NQsVNmCABADFJATSsARfgEkHi5SCJkKGkAy69FjM7Jy8VHaOLu72niq%206lRgQfohhuEmIAASgpKuAMISACoi8d6qfsmpBmHGVNmuAOLZVgBCkqKiTlbiwoIAygMAqv2KALpKAVzoALY8OHAAjHQMvAzQeKAA7ixgUAAW8ADsAAyndAcYLADmB1DwAMwArBcgUEwQCwBmXEyzWxA3xYKCgGCY8FAbAgnwBmi0TDQWCOCgU4zoKAgxHBgNmMIA1pD3sQ2BgqEwMAwHlMMDw1mAWDwbkTiETgRgUClND41JQ6FASWTNDwuLNGahPCAAB5slgcrnBUJGCL8wVUEVingSugQKUsRagP5yngPTRQLhsIKYrQc-hMlBC06o1GTLy7fZHOBnN5XW73J5vPFMQmaGEYWggWn0xnMhDS2Xy5K1ZV8VWk9Wi8UoIK6-XwHhoFAoKasuPszlUHlVNNCkAarM5vWLAtF1F0aGwxb4OsQWa1hFIo50ZDoIW4EBmCTSORBScWOS2BzONweOhRZexIK5fJFcSlYRb5qtDpdHp9QYjMbokBYDmU02gAXpzSMsFMEdBKNcBlMrvxyZooBQA)

i want like this label of x axis----

```
                 AEROPLANE
                 FLY
                 DAILY
```

i tried using list data-type but getting issues when using list of string values in scroller..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
{
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"Key_data": "a", "description": "AEROPLANE"},
      {"Key_data": "b", "description": "AEROPLANE FLY DAILY"},
      {"Key_data": "c", "description": "FLY DAILY"},
      {"Key_data": "d", "description": "HELICOPTER"},
      {"Key_data": "d", "description": "HIGH BLOOD PRESSURE"}
    ]
  },
  "columns": 1,
  "concat": [
    {
      "width": 700,
      "height": 350,
      "transform": [{"filter": {"param": "brush"}}],
      "layer": [
        {
          "mark": {"type": "rect"},
          "encoding": {
            "y": {"field": "Key_data", "type": "nominal"},
            "x": {
              "field": "description",
              "type": "nominal",
              "axis": {
                "orient": "top",
                "labelAngle": 0,
                "labelExpr": "split(datum.label,' ')",
                "labelPadding": 25
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "width": 700,
      "height": 30,
      "mark": "area",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "description", "type": "nominal", "axis": null},
        "y": {"field": "Key_data", "type": "nominal", "axis": null}
      },
      "params": [
        {
          "name": "brush",
          "value": [
            "AEROPLANE",
            "AEROPLANE FLY DAILY",
            "FLY DAILY",
            "HELICOPTER",
            "HIGH BLOOD PRESSURE"
          ],
          "select": {"type": "interval", "encodings": ["x"]}
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```